# JS build object recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, indexing, fs

I am attempting to build a file-structure index using nodeJS. I'm using the fs.readir function to iterate the files, which works fine. My problem is descending into the directory structure and returning a full object with the correct structure.

I have a simple function named identify which, when given file name "myfile.txt" will return an object {name: "myfile", type: "txt"}, which will explain that part of the function below...

My problem is that nothing is being returned when I run the indexer into the "me" variable. The console.log(results) line does return, however. This leaves me quite confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
indexer = 
    function(directory){     
        Self.indexleft++;
        var results = {};
        Self.client.readdir(directory, function(err,fileLst){
            if(err){ return; }
            for(var count=0; count < fileLst.length; count++){
                var ident = identify(fileLst[count]);
                if(ident.type = 'dir'){
                    var descendant = (directory !== '') ? 
                        directory + '\\' + ident.name : ident.name;
                    ident.children = indexer(descendant);
                                }
                    //directory = (directory.split('\\').pop());
                    results[ident.name] = ident;
                 }
                 console.log(results);
                 return results;
             });
         }
         var me = indexer(''); console.log(me);
```

EDIT:: 
I've actually got something working now, though it's not quite as elegant as I'd like. Below is what I did. If anyone has a suggestion on optimizing I'd be happy to hear it!!

**Newest (working) Code:**

```
var events = require('events'),
    event = new events.EventEmitter(),
setToValue = function(obj, value, path) {
    path = path.split('\\');
    for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++)
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    obj[path[i]] = value;
},
identify = function(file){
    var split = file.split('.'),
        type = (split.length > 1) ? split.pop() : 'dir',
        filename = split.join('.');
    return { name: filename, type: type };
};
Indexer = function(cli,dir,callback){  
    this.client = cli; // File reading client
    this.startDir = dir; // Starting directory
    this.results = {}; // Result object
    this.running = 0; // How many itterations of start() are running
    this.start(dir); // Start indexing
    this.monit(); // Start never returns anything, monit() checks ever 5 seconds and will fire callback if 0 itterations are running.
    this.callbackDone = false; // Checks whether the callback has already been fired. Important in case of interval staggering
    this.cb = callback;
}
Indexer.prototype = {
    start: function(directory){        
        var Self = this;
        Self.running++;
        Self.client.readdir(directory, function(err,fileLst){
            if(err){ Self.running--; return; }
            for(var count=0; count < fileLst.length; count++){
                var ident = identify(fileLst[count]);
                var descendant = (directory !== '') ? directory + '\\' + ident.name : ident.name;
                if(ident.type === 'dir'){                
                    Self.start(descendant);
                }
                setToValue(Self.results, ident, descendant);
            }
            Self.running--;
            console.log('running' + Self.running);
        });
    },
    monit: function(){
        var Self = this;
        Self.intervalA = setInterval(function(){
            if(Self.running < 1){                
                if(!Self.callbackDone){ 
                    this.callbackDone=true; 
                    Self.cb(Self.results);
                }
                clearInterval(Self.intervalA);

            }
        }, 5000)
    }
}

var ix = new Indexer(Self.client,'',function(res){
                        console.log("Index Complete!");
                        fs.writeFile(path.join(Self.localLibBase,'/index.json'), JSON.stringify(res), (err)=> {
                            console.log("FileWrite Complete!");
                        });
                    });
```

Example of returned object structure :

```
{
    "Applications" : {
        "name" : "Applications",
        "type" : "dir",
        "Microsoft Exchange Server 2007" : {
            "name" : "Microsoft Exchange Server 2007",
            "type" : "dir",
            "Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP1" : {
                "name" : "Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP1",
                "type" : "iso"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous. `me` will not equal anything until `indexer()` finishes, but `console.log(me)` will execute immediately.

Comment: Look into promises.

Comment: Can you provide a sample directory structure and an expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The result is only available asynchronously, so you are trying to output the result too soon. The inner code is only executed later.

You can solve this in many ways. A very nice solution to working with asynchronous code is using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

As you have a recursive call, you'll have to resolve that with promises too.

NB: Note you had a bug in the comparison with "dir": you assigned instead of comparing.

Here is how your code would look:

```
var indexer = function(directory) {
    // return a promise object
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Self.indexleft++;
        var results = {};
        Self.client.readdir(directory, function(err,fileLst){
            if(err) { 
                reject(); // promise is rejected
                return;
            }
            // "Iterate" over file list asyonchronously
            (function nextFile(fileList) {
                if (!fileList.length) {
                    resolve(results);  // promise is resolved
                    return;
                }
                var file = fileLst.shift(); // shop off first file
                var ident = identify(file); 
                results[ident.name] = ident;
                if(ident.type === 'dir'){ // There was a bug here: equal sign!
                    var descendant = directory !== '' 
                            ? directory + '\\' + ident.name : ident.name;
                    // recursively call indexer: it is again a promise!        
                    indexer(descendant).then(function (result) {
                        ident.children = result;
                        // recursively continue with next file from list
                        nextFile(fileList);
                    });
                } else {
                    nextFile(fileLst);
                }
            })(fileLst); // start first iteration with full list
        });
    });
};

// Call as a promise. Result is passed async to callback. 
indexer('').then(function(me) {
    console.log(me);
});
```

I made some dummy functions for your external references to make this snippet work:

```js
// Below code added to mimic the external references -- can be ignored
var filesystem = [
    "",
    "images",
    "images\\photo.png",
    "images\\backup",
    "images\\backup\\old_photo.png",
    "images\\backup\\removed_pic.jpg",
    "images\\panorama.jpg",
    "docs",
    "docs\\essay.doc",
    "readme.txt",
];

var Self = {
    indexLeft: 0,
    client: {
        readdir: function (directory, callback) {
            var list = filesystem.filter( path => 
                    path.indexOf(directory) == 0 
                    && path.split('\\').length == directory.split('\\').length + (directory!=='')
                    && path !== directory
            ).map ( path => path.split('\\').pop() );
            setTimeout(callback.bind(null, 0, list), 100);
        }
    }
}

function identify(item) {
    return {
        name: item,
        type: item.indexOf('.') > -1 ? 'file' : 'dir'
    };
}
// Above code added to mimic the external references -- can be ignored

var indexer = function(directory) {
    // return a promise object
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Self.indexleft++;
        var results = {};
        Self.client.readdir(directory, function(err,fileLst){
            if(err) { 
                reject(); // promise is rejected
                return;
            }
            // "Iterate" over file list asyonchronously
            (function nextFile(fileList) {
                if (!fileList.length) {
                    resolve(results);  // promise is resolved
                    return;
                }
                var file = fileLst.shift(); // shop off first file
                var ident = identify(file); 
                results[ident.name] = ident;
                if(ident.type === 'dir'){ // There was a bug here: equal sign!
                    var descendant = directory !== '' 
                            ? directory + '\\' + ident.name : ident.name;
                    // recursively call indexer: it is again a promise!        
                    indexer(descendant).then(function (result) {
                        ident.children = result;
                        // recursively continue with next file from list
                        nextFile(fileList);
                    });
                } else {
                    nextFile(fileLst);
                }
            })(fileLst); // start first iteration with full list
        });
    });
};

// Call as a promise. Result is passed async to callback. 
indexer('').then(function(me) {
    console.log(me);
});
```

Comment: Hi trincot, this looks excellent! Unfortunately it doesn't actually work. It has a similar problem to my previous code, namely that it never returns anything. I'm thinking maybe it gets stuck in a recursion loop or something? I tried removing the reject() on error, since I still want the callback in the case of an error in that particular place... Your description of the problem is definitely accurate though, it's due to the asynchronous nature of the code. I'll add my latest code which is working above. It's not as elegant as I'd like though, so maybe you'll have more ideas?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Put some `console.log` statements at different places to see what it does. As I don't have your `Self` object, `identify` function, etc, I cannot test this code.

Comment: Yes sir, I've added console logs in several places and once again everything within seems to work. (Logging the results within the function works fine) but the callback is never fired. :(

Comment: The final callback *should* be fired when `resolve` is called. Are you sure it gets there? I do see I need to do something for the recursive call `ident.children = indexer(descendant);`. Could you put that in comments until you spot the problem? It will make it easier to debug

Comment: Sure, except, I'm not sure what you want in the comments?

Comment: I mean: remove that statement (put it in comments `// ident.children = indexer(descendant);`). In the meantime I am going to create the variables you have with a dummy file structure, so I can test the code myself. It will take a while, but I'll get there.

Comment: No worries, I'll be happy to implement the promise solution over the one I've got. It seems much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my updated answer with working code (assuming your `readdir` and `identify` functions are OK).

Comment: Did this work out for you? Could you leave a comment?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I had to just continue using the method I added to the question. I'm sure I could eventually figure out what needs to be changed (via debugging and trial and error...) for now I've had to move on with the project since it's "Working well enough." :/

Answer (score 0):

It's not really obvious how you're expecting to that returned object from the code you have, but I can help you get the object nonetheless.

The shape of the object is bad because you're using filenames as keys on the object but that's wrong. Keys should be identifiers known to your program, and since filenames can be almost anything, using a filename as a key is terrible.

For example, consider if a file was named `name` in your structure

```
{ "Applications" : {
    "name" : "Applications",
    "type" : "dir",
    "name" : {
      "name" : "name"
       ... } } }
```

Yep, it just broke. Don't worry tho, our solution won't run into such troubles.

```
const co = require('co')
const {stat,readdir} = require('fs')
const {extname,join} = require('path')

// "promisified" fs functions
const readdirp = path =>
  new Promise ((t,f) => readdir (path, (err, res) => err ? f (err) : t (res)))

const statp = fd =>
  new Promise ((t,f) => stat (fd, (err,stats) => err ? f (err) : t (stats)))

// tree data constructors
const Dir = (path, children) =>
  ({type: 'd', path, children})

const File = (path, ext) =>
  ({type: 'f', path, ext})

// your function
const indexer = function* (path) {
  const stats = yield statp (path)
  if (stats.isDirectory ())
    return Dir (path, yield (yield readdirp (path)) .map (p => indexer (join (path,p))))
  else
    return File (path, extname (path))
}
```

This is good design because we didn't tangle directory tree building in with whatever `Self.client` is. Parsing a directory and building a tree is its own thing, and if you need an Object to inherit that behaviour there are other ways to do it.

Ok let's setup a sample tree of files and then run it

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/disk.iso foo/image.jpg foo/readme.txt
$ mkdir foo/bar
$ touch foo/bar/build foo/bar/code.js foo/bar/migrate.sql
```

Using `indexer` is easy

```
// co returns a Promise
// once indexer is done, you will have a fully built tree
co (indexer ('./test')) .then (
  tree => console.log (JSON.stringify (tree, null, '  ')),
  err  => console.error (err.message)
)
```

Output (some `\n` removed for brevity)

```
{
  "type": "d",
  "path": "./foo",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "d",
      "path": "foo/bar",
      "children": [
        { "type": "f", "path": "foo/bar/build", "ext": "" },
        { "type": "f", "path": "foo/bar/code.js", "ext": ".js" },
        { "type": "f", "path": "foo/bar/migrate.sql", "ext": ".sql" }
      ]
    },
    { "type": "f", "path": "foo/disk.iso", "ext": ".iso" },
    { "type": "f", "path": "foo/image.jpg", "ext": ".jpg" },
    { "type": "f", "path": "foo/readme.txt", "ext": ".txt" }
  ]
}
```

---

If you try `indexer` on a path to a file, it will not fail

```
co (indexer ('./test/foo/disk.iso')) .then (
  tree => console.log (JSON.stringify (tree, null, '  ')),
  err  => console.error (err.message)
)
```

Output

```
{ "type": "f", "path": "./foo/disk.iso", "ext": ".iso" }
```