# How do I return from a recursive generator function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I'm playing around with a recursive generator function that returns values asynchronously. I'm using a coroutine wrapper function to call it. Code and JSBin below:

http://jsbin.com/nuyovay/edit?js,console

```
let log = console.log.bind(console);
let err = console.error.bind(console);

function coroutine(generatorFn){
    return function co() {
        let generator = generatorFn.apply(this, arguments);

        function handle(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.done) {
                return Promise.resolve(result.value);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(result.value)
                .then(
                    res => handle(generator.next(res)),
                    err => handle(generator.throw(err))
                );
        }

        try {
            return handle(generator.next());
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    };
}

function sleep(dur) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => { res() }, dur);
    });
}

function* recurse(limit = 5, count = 0) {   
    if(count < limit) {
        yield sleep(100).then(() => Promise.resolve(++count));
        yield* recurse(limit, count);
    }
    else {
        return count;
    }
}

let test = coroutine(recurse);

test().then(log).catch(err);
```

Running this returns:

```
Object {value: Promise, done: false}
Object {value: Promise, done: false}
Object {value: Promise, done: false}
Object {value: Promise, done: false}
Object {value: Promise, done: false}
// `value` should be 5
Object {value: undefined, done: true}
```

How come the final `return` from the generator is `undefined`? When I adapt the above for use with bluebird's `Promise.coroutine`, I get the same result. Am I missing something fundamental about recursive generators? How do I get it to `{ value: 5, done: true }`?

Comment: related: [JS build object recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39154757/633183) (answer uses [tj/co](https://github.com/tj/co))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning `count`, but you're returning it in the parent generator. Unlike `yield` in delegated generators, `return` is not yielded back up through the delegation chain automatically.

If you want to get the `return` value of a delegated generator, you have to assign it directly in the parent generator:

```
let returnValue = yield* recurse(limit, count);
```

Since you're using "recursive" generators (multiple levels of delegation), you would need to repeat the process and return the value at every level of delegation:

```
function* recurse(limit = 5, count = 0) {   
    if(count < limit) {
        yield sleep(100).then(() => Promise.resolve(++count));
        let result = yield* recurse(limit, count); // save the return value
        return result; // return it to the parent
    }
    else {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `if` you only have a `return` on one side.

You also don't need to use the `.then` inside your generator. The whole point of using the generator is so that you don't have to touch the promise API within.

Instead, call `recurse` with `count + 1`

```
function* recurse(limit = 5, count = 0) {
  if(count < limit) {
    yield sleep(1000).then(() => Promise.resolve(++count));
    return yield* recurse(limit, count + 1);
  }
  else {
    return count;
  }
}
```

And since you're using ES6, while we're at it …

```
return function co() {
    let generator = generatorFn.apply(this, arguments);
```

… is better off as …

```
return function co(...args) {
    let generator = generatorFn(...args)
```

---

**all together now**

Run the snippet and you'll see the correct output right here

```js
let log = console.log.bind(console);
let err = console.error.bind(console);

function coroutine(generatorFn){
  return function co(...args) {
    let generator = generatorFn(...args)

    function handle(result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.done) {
        return Promise.resolve(result.value);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(result.value)
        .then(
          res => handle(generator.next(res)),
          err => handle(generator.throw(err))
        );
    }

    try {
      return handle(generator.next());
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  };
}

function sleep(dur) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => { res() }, dur);
  });
}

function* recurse(limit = 5, count = 0) {  
  if(count < limit) {
    yield sleep(100)
    return yield* recurse(limit, count + 1);
  }
  else {
    return count;
  }
}

let test = coroutine(recurse);

test().then(log).catch(err);
```

Comment: Didn't know you could return a `yield`. That keyword continues to blow my mind. +1 for that.

Comment: `yield` is can be place in any place where a normal expression can be placed AFAIK. It just halts execution and start with the next call to `next` again.

Comment: @conokes, I will add, `yield` sends a value *out* of the generator and pauses the execution. If you call `.next` with a value (like you've done using `.next(res)`, that sends a value back *in* to the generator – You can think of this incoming value as the "return" of the `yield`.

Comment: @conokes, to be clear, if I `return yield foo()`, and then I call `gen.next(10)`, the value sent to the `return` statement is `10`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wonder: this is not how the `coroutine` helper is meant to be used. The function itself should recurse through the wrapperd version, like this:

```js
let log = console.log.bind(console);
let err = console.error.bind(console);

function coroutine(generatorFn){
    return function co() {
        let generator = generatorFn.apply(this, arguments);

        function handle(result) {
            // console.log(result);
            if (result.done) {
                return Promise.resolve(result.value);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(result.value)
                .then(
                    res => handle(generator.next(res)),
                    err => handle(generator.throw(err))
                );
        }

        try {
            return handle(generator.next());
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    };
}

function sleep(dur) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => { res() }, dur);
    });
}

const recurse = coroutine(function* (
  limit = 5, count = 0
) {   
  if(count < limit) {
    yield sleep(100);
    ++count;
    return yield recurse(limit, count);
  } else {
    return count;
  }
});


recurse().then(log).catch(err);
```

### Why?

An asynchronous function is defined as regular function, returning `Promise`, and never throwing a synchronous exception. The `coroutine` helper just helps you write asynchronous functions. If you are familiar with async/await from other languages, this wrapper is intended to convert generators to asynchronous functions, where all `await`s are replaced by `yield`s. These functions are easier to reason about with this in mind, so people don't have to argue about generators, just asynchronous functions.

Comment: Interesting. Can you expand more on why?

Comment: Added some explanation.