# Recursive Generator Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, generator

The for loop is not returning the increasing count variable.

It acts as though the range function is not being called, but it is.

```
function* range (limit, count = 0) {
  if (count >= limit) return
  yield count
  range(limit, count + 1) 
} 


for (let i of range(16)) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: [Generator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return from a recursive generator function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171411/how-do-i-return-from-a-recursive-generator-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `yield *` the range from your generator function.

Give this a try:

```
function* range (limit, count = 0) {
  if (count >= limit) return
  yield count
  yield * range(limit, count + 1) 
} 


for (let i of range(16)) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Because it's recursive you need to yield the result back up to the parent basically.